# Cascading Parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have looked at various ways of doing this but cant seem to implement it correctly.

I have a 3 parameter report in SSRS

@County
 @LocalAuthority
 @Ward

I want these parameters cascading. So when  @county is chosen @LocalAuthority only displays local authorities within that county.  And when local authorities are chosen only the wards in those authorities appear.

the County to Local Authority is working but Local Authority to Ward isn't. The correct wards are showing in the drop down parameter but they are not filtering by ward in the actual report.

I am using stored procedures.
This is my main dataset

```
  @County varchar (5),
  @LocalAuthority varchar (max),
  @Ward varchar (max)

   SELECT

             [DateTimeOfCall] 
            ,HourOfDay 
        ,[ConcatAddress] 
        ,[LocalAuthority]
        ,[Ward] 
        ,[County] 
        ,[PropertyType]

FROM table1

WHERE   [County] = @County AND [LocalAuthority] = @LocalAuthority and 

[Ward] in @Ward
```

2nd dataset for local authority

```
    @County varchar (5)       

         SELECT DISTINCT

                LocalAuthority,
        county              

              FROM table1

  WHERE [County] = @County
```

and a final dataset for Ward

```
         @LocalAuthority (max)

        SELECT DISTINCT


        Ward,
        LocalAuthority 


              FROM table1

       WHERE [LocalAuthority] = @LocalAuthority
```

Many Thanks

Comment: What do you get in Ward now?

Comment: I think you are not mapping SSRS parameters to SQL parameters, are you?

Comment: yes sorry I didn't explain myself, the correct wards are showing in the drop down parameter but its not filtering the wards in the report

Comment: If your parameter is set to allow multiple values you only need to use `where ... [Ward] in (@Ward)`

Comment: Further to @alejandrozuleta, this is good practice anyway, in case of changes further down the line

Comment: Assuming I've understood....I've made this change in the main dataset....'WHERE   [County] = atCounty AND [LocalAuthority] = atLocalAuthority and [Ward] in (atWard)' ....this is bringing back nothing in the report

Comment: In SSRS  @Ward parameter is set to _allow multiple values_?

Comment: yes it is. I'm getting the correct wards in the drop down, just no data appearing when I review the report

Comment: what happens if you select your main dataset explicitly by query instead of stored procedure? does it return data to the report?

Comment: yes data is returned when I do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead of ward in @ward if you wanted to get the dataset via stored procedure:

```
CHARINDEX(','+ward+',', ','+@ward+',') > 0
```

Comment: Fantastic that has worked! Thankyou.  What exactly does that mean??

Comment: this is because the parameter is passed as a comma separated string

Comment: I added the commas so if you are looking for a Jo it won't get confused with  John :)